# Ebay API: Get only auction type listings for search query return no results

Tags: ebay-api

On ebay's Browse API, I'm trying to get only listings that are auctions, but get no results.

For example, I'm trying to get auctions for iphones (or any other keyword), using buyingOptions filter:

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=iphone&filter=buyingOptions:{AUCTION}
```

Yet, I get no results.

If I edit the above query, to also include FIXED_PRICE items, I will get only fixed price results:

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=iphone&filter=buyingOptions:{AUCTION|FIXED_PRICE}
```

Is it possible to get only auction type items? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from sandbox to production api solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on the production API. What I finally tried was URL encoding the string, and that worked.

I'm using the Laravel HTTP Client to do my calls and never had to URL encode anything before, this particular string required it, perhaps because of the brackets.

```
&filter=buyingOptions:{AUCTION}
```

I used the PHP urlencode() on that string.